# Why is flow from a holding tank diminishing after a few seconds?

Tags: water-pressure

Context: We've had a gravity-fed spring for 20 years (no pumps or electricity..all gravity). The spring and the concrete holding tank are about 1,000 feet up the mountain from our house.

Problem:
Recently, we noticed that the water pressure is fine for about 30 seconds and then slows to a trickle. Or, if the water pressure is fine in a sink, it drops to a trickle when flushing toilet.

If you wait a while, the pressure returns, only to diminish when you turn it on for about 30 seconds.

Response:
I pulled the lid off the concrete tank.
It's full of water.
It's overflowing over the overflow pipe.
We looked to the (not sure what you call it) the output pipe at the bottom of the tank. It appeared to be unclogged.

Possible problem?
We're thinking maybe the overflow line is clogged and that blowing it out would help.
Does this sound correct?

Comment: Does "1,000 feet up the mountain" refer to elevation or distance? Sounds like you're developing a partial vacuum. A vent or overflow is clogged, or there's a partial clog in the supply line. Hard to say through the internet.

Comment: Great question! It's distance but there's significant increase in elevation as well. Not sure how much. I can walk up and measure the difference. In any event, it's worked well for 20 years so I guess the elevation is working?

Comment: I assume that the overflow just dumps excess water to continue flowing down a stream bed or something. Do you have any mechanical reason to expect that the clogged overflow has anything to do with the problem? Or did you just notice that it's not working correctly? Seeing whatever the overflow blockage is may hint at the cause of the other blockage, so clearing it sounds like a good step #1.

Comment: "the pressure returns" seems like it conflates pressure with flow

Answer (score 11):

The overflow being "clogged" could easily cause a (partial) vacuum in the supply tank that would have this effect, if the overflow is also the only vent on the tank. What happens if you run water with the tank lid partly open?

If the problem goes away, it's an issue with venting air into the tank. Our springs have typically been set up with a screened air vent to let air in while keeping creatures out.

If the problem remains it's some sort of blockage in the supply line. That can be as embarrassing but easy as a partially closed valve, or more difficult. If there's a point where you can open the full bore of the pipe down the hill for a strong cleanout flow, that might be worth doing.

Answer (score 7):

Sure sounds like a partial blockage somewhere in the feed pipe.  Could be some debris, a buildup of scum, mineral deposits, rust buildup, or other growths inside the feed pipe, or even possibly a partially crushed pipe that's causing significant flow restriction.  I assume this happens on all fixtures inside your house (indicating a problem upstream)?  If the water flows well for a bit, then slows down, that indicates to me that the restriction is up a ways.  But it doesn't sound easy to fix, as you'll need to try and find where the blockage might be, and I assume this is buried pipe, so will be more of a challenge to dig up.  If you don't see anything clogging the pipe at the holding tank, you might need to get a plumber in to try and use a scope to go down the pipe to see what it looks like inside.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately no answer has provided every possibility.

Blocked air vent for the tank. This venting of the tank could be implemented as the overflow outlet or a separate air vent. Whatever method is used to provide an air vent it will have a fine filter mesh to keep out small insects such as mosquitoes. Overtime these can be block by vegetation or remains of small animals e.g. water snail shells, bird nests, wasps or whatever are can be a problem in that locality. Regular maintenance/cleaning is all that should be required.

Restrictions in the tank blocking the entrance to the supply line. This could be due the build up of material in the bottom of the tank. Regular maintenance is the solution, Unfortunately more difficult than a blocked air vent.

Restrictions in the supply line which could have a single answer or be a combination of the following issues. This could be due to material from inside the tank entering the line and restricting flow. Rust in supply line contributing to a reduction in diameter but for obvious reasons not so likely with a plastic supply line. Tree or plant roots entering the line at a joint. Mechanically crushed supply line. Material from the tank entering the supply line and restricting flow at bends, valves, pressure regulators, water filters or any other point in the line where material can accumulate.

Somebody has played with a valve in the supply line e.g. children have partially closed a valve or tap.

Comment: Birds' nest in the vent. Or wasps. Or a hibernating squirrel (or whatever OP has in his unstated locale).

Comment: Thank you, updated the text